# Creating a .NET 8 Blazor server on VS Code

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, blazor

.NET 8 is out and I want to create a Blazor server in VS Code.

When I try `dotnet new blazorserver -f net8.0` in the terminal, it returns

> 'net8.0' is not a valid value for -f

How should I do it in VS Code?

Comment: any update? Do you have any other issue according to my answer?

Comment: Yes, it is working now. I guess Microsoft just simplified the name blazorserver into blazor now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-new-sdk-templates#blazorserver), the `blazorserver` template doesn't contain the `-f` option.

You should use `blazor` instead.

Try to run this command:

```
dotnet new blazor -f net8.0 -o blazorserverapptest
```

Result:

[image]